# Is there a biological way for a shroom to control its gnome host?

Tags: internal-consistency, fantasy-races

I know "Zombie Mushrooms" exist, but what is the feasibility of a shroom that is able to somehow control its host by a preferably physical way? Ex: I had the idea of it jabbing into the spinal cord.

Note: The shroom is large enough to appear as a 3-4ft diameter mushroom cap on the gnome. The shroom also is able to use the gnome's biological systems to feed itself.

The shroom should be able to move by itself by slithering around when it's looking for a host or migrating.

Comment: I feel like the reality-check and fantasy-races tags are incompatible here.  Additionally, if the mushroom can move on its own, it's not a mushroom as anyone in our world would define the term.

Comment: Have you read Jeff Vandermeer's Ambergris stories?  I recommend "[Dradin, in Love](http://www.infinityplus.co.uk/stories/dradin2.htm)" and _[Shriek: An Afterword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shriek:_An_Afterword)_.  He solves this problem to n a creepy way.

Comment: Why change what nature perfected here? Use of chemical signaling to control the host is a pretty ideal method. Some reason you need it to be a direct signaling approach? Also, why not allow the mushroom to grow from the host?

Comment: If this can work, then the gnome would be a really fun-guy.

Comment: The spinal cord isn't physical control.

Comment: @jdunlop the idea is they evolved from parasitic shrooms and somehow gained motor functions to make finding a host easier

Comment: @Spencer I have not but I'm going to now

Comment: @Samuel I could have a mix of chemical control as well as physical roots. I didn't factor in chemical control being enough to control a host

Comment: some Cordyceps works by physically burrowing into the brain and nervous system of the ants it takes over and releasing neurochemical directly into it, how is your system any different?

Comment: When I looked those Cordyceps up they only seemed to be able to do simple tasks with the ants. My shrooms need to do much more being able to control sentient beings and be able to do complex tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creature you describe is almost completely unlike a mushroom, so I'm going to widen the question to "can one creature control another in a physical way?"

It all depends on what you mean by control.  If by control you mean being able to cause [quivvering](https://youtu.be/LPyoFJGyQoU?t=1m27s) contractions of the muscles, then it is easy.  All you need to be able to do is apply a small voltage near the correct nerve as it exits the spinal column to achieve the desired effect.

There are also plenty of ways to get better control than that via pain.  If your parasite causes pain signals whenever the host does something they don't want, then it will be easy to convince the host not to do those things.  The response from noxiceptors tends to be a rather random and unpredictable, so they're easy signals to fake.

If you want to develop *meaningful* control, like the creature from [Invasion of the Body Snatchers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52vK2-Dv1TA) it's going to be dramatically harder.  Our spinal column doesn't have a bunch of nerves labeled like the directions on a joystick or controller pad.  We don't have a "move forward" nerve.  It's also not a simple wire, like a USB cable.  In fact, the spinal column does a remarkably large amount of processing to keep us upright.  If you bump your right hand into a wall while walking, your left leg will adjust its gait *before* the signal has even reached the lower brain, much less before the brain gets a chance to respond.  The spinal column maintains our balance impeccably with neural networks embedded in it.

Thus any host trying to control a body this way is going to have to *learn* that specific host's spinal cord, and learn how it responds.  It basically is going to have to act like the host's brain, talking a specific language the host's brain and spinal column invented during the lifetime of the host.

Indeed, solving this sort of problem is at the heart of the [full-body-transplant](http://www.businessinsider.com/head-transplant-surgeon-beat-mortality-death-aging-2017-6) a.k.a. head transplant.  The brain has its work cut out for itself, trying to figure out how someone else's spinal column worked.

Instead, the most tempting solutions are those in the brain, like the Zombie Fungus uses.  The brain, for the most part, is even more complicated than the spinal column.  However, it already had existing structure that we can rely on.  For example, we generally know where sensory experiences are found. Brain surgeons may stimulate them to map where they are within the brain.  There are also structures in the brain that are hardwired at the genetic level (which are the kind of structures the zombie mushroom takes advantage of when taking over an ant).  A parasite has a much better chance of taking over meaningfully at this level.

Alternatively, the parasite could simply *do* its own full body transplant, snipping the spinal column and taking over.  In this case, expect the host to move more like a zombie, lacking any dynamic control whatsoever (because the parasite isn't taking advantage of the dynamic capabilities of the spinal column for balance).  However, over time, it may be able to learn to teach the spinal column to speak a language it understands.  Perhaps after 10 years of controlling a host, they might be able to speak.

If you really do want to go the physical way, my recommendation would be to give the host an spinal injection in the lumbar region.  Our spinal column breaks apart into a bunch of strands in that region, so it's harder to damage.  If you're not squeamish, here's a video of a dissection of the spine: https://www.you tube.com/watch?v=ODtmzSdLeYc (intentionally broke the link in to two parts because it is NSFW and *very* graphic!  It is a dissection of an actual human cadaver.  The first thing you see is the back of a deceased human, with the skin and adipose tissue already removed.  This can be disconcerting if you aren't ready for it.).  Around minute 9 they start opening the spinal cord itself.  It demonstrates precisely what such a parasite would be interacting with when it pierces into the spinal cord and tries to take control.

That video shows how the parasite would want to trace the individual strands of nerves to their exit points, and then start trying to take control.  Also, conveniently, at this region, motor and sensory fibers are separated, making it easier to avoid hurting the host (pain).  Once you have some minimal ambulatory control, you might be able to walk your host away from their civilization long enough to gain more control.

Comment: Hmm thanks for the answer! I think the zombie walk would work while the more experienced shrooms would become more agile.

Answer (score 0):

Mushrooms are the flowering bodies of certain species of fungus. The fungus is made up of mycellium, thread like filaments that spread through the host and consume. In any case, the shroom would spread its filaments into the host brain and control the motor functions and even manipulate memory and desire.

How does the filaments push through the skull though? Slow process like roots pushing through the ground, some kind of mosquito like barb that can punch a tiny hole through, a probiscus that can spit acid which eats away or softens the skull to allow penetration. Various ways to do it.

Or bypass the skull altogether and have the shroom invade through the eye, nose, ear or back of the neck. Similar to your spine idea but the shroom winds around the spinal cord and attaches to the brain, like a goa'uld from Stargate.

Mobility would be by bunching up its filaments and using them like legs. Caps would be light and designed to float so that shrooms could attach themselves to trees or other high objects and float down onto their target.
If you go with the slow approach to invading the brain then the shrooms should have a contact toxin which imobilises the host long enough for penetration to be achieved. Otherwise the shrooms could excrete an organic glue on contact which gives them enough time to take over.

Comment: I like the gliding bit as well as the toxin. Going to, for sure, add that to the shrooms.